# Avoid postback when getting dropdownlist value c# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pageload

I've dynamically created a `dropdownlist` within C# (No code in asp):

```
DropDownList myDDL = new DropDownList();
```

This can't be called from `pageLoad()` as it's not loaded everytime the page refreshes. However it's loaded everytime OnPostback(`OnSelectedIndexChanged()`) of another dll so I cant do `!IsPostBack`.

---

This dll is created when:

- A value of another `dropdownlist` populates a `GridView` using `OnSelectedIndexChanged()`

  ```
  <asp:DropDownList id ="select1" name="assignGetForm"  runat="server" class="selectClass" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="populateGridView">
  ```
- On the `GridView` a function is run `OnRowDatabound()`(when the above `OnIndexChanged()` populates it) to populate *myDDL* inside the `GridView`

  ```
  <asp:GridView id="GridView1" name="GridView1" onrowdatabound="populateCellsDDL" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
  ```

I'm now trying to access the values in `myDDL` using a button `onclick()` event - however this always does postback and refreshes the page so `myDDL` dissapears and when I print the value to console it just gives my first value `select activity` and not the one i've actually selected.

How would I get these values when they are changed as this dll is not populated on `pageLoad()`.
I've tried looking at AJAX however i'm unsure how to look at the c# value through this. I tried aswell `viewstates` but i dont have luck as again it doesnt populate on `pageLoad()`.

Comment: Have you looked at the Page.IsPostBack property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx . You can check whether the page is being posted back and prevent reloading

Comment: Yeah, if I wrap my button bind in !ispostback it doesn't bind because I am posting back on the other ddl.. however not the pageload.

Then when I press the button to get my values (DDL.SelectedValue) it postsback therefore losing the created DDL as they aren't populated on pageload! It's all going around in circle hhaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to rebind the grid in each postback, if you want to access values of dynamically created controls.

I tried to simulate the situation with below sample code and I was able to access the value successfully.

ASPX code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="select1" name="assignGetForm" runat="server" class="selectClass" AutoPostBack="True" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" name="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

C# code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        FillMainDll();

    if (!IsPostBack || GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        BindGrid();
}

private void FillMainDll()
{
    select1.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    select1.DataBind();
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr[0] = i;
        dr[1] = "Name - " + i.ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var myDDL = new DropDownList();
        myDDL.ID = "myDDL";
        myDDL.DataSource = GetGridRowDdlData();
        myDDL.DataBind();
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(myDDL);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetGridRowDdlData()
{
    var data = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        data.Add("Name - " + i * int.Parse(select1.SelectedValue));
    }

    return data;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        var myDDL = row.FindControl("myDDL") as DropDownList;
        if (myDDL != null)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}<br/>", myDDL.SelectedValue);
        }
    }

    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, bind the grid so the rowdatabound fires.. I'll have a look at this at reply how it works thanks!!